# Catalina.sh gives error while setting up memory size

Tags: java, shell, tomcat, memory, catalina

Whenever I run tomcat, I get this error

`/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 236: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m: command not found` though the tomcat starts after deployment but after sometime i do get outofmemory errors.

I looked at `catalina.sh:236` and I see this line there

`JAVA_OPTS=-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss64M`

whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks are missing. Change it to:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss64M"
```

Comment: o wao. didn't notice that.

Comment: @EmAe Did it fix your problem?

Comment: it did solve the issue but created another problem. Since i am deploying through Idea, any script (`catalina.sh` in this case) which uses `JAVA_OPTS` overrides Idea settings and hence idea can't deploy it there

Comment: have you tried something to preserve JAVA_OPTS settings, like: JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss64M"? I never used Idea, so I'm not sure what's the problem